# mkdir inside sh, won't work

Tags: command-line, sh, mkdir

I am trying to create directory using mkdir inside sh file, when I do that the directory is created, but then when trying to do something to it, I get the message "rm: cannot remove '/testFolder': No such file or directory", but it is there...

What am i doing wrong?

this is my sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /testFolder
wget https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/bb2b6b1aefcd70dfd1892149ac3a215f6c636b07/server.jar -O /testFolder/server.jar
echo "cd /testFolder\njava -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui" >> /testFolder/startMc.sh
```

then i call the file `sudo sh test.sh`

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Why are you trying to create `testFolder` in `/`, not in `~`?

Comment: I am using ubuntu server 19 well i could try that, did not think of that

Comment: There is no `ubuntu server 19` release. Remove `/` in front of `testFolder` and all should work.

Comment: Still does not work..

Comment: What doesn't work? Does `mkdir testFolder` work? Are there any errors. Most likely you don't run the script. Please [edit] your question and add all steps you do.

Comment: `testFolder` and `/testFolder` are different. Did you try to `rm testFolder`?

Comment: I did try that, nothing works :s

Comment: Why are you trying to ceate a direcoty in the root of filesystem? It is unclear what you want to achieve. You don't need `sudo` to create a directory in a proper place.

Comment: I am not sure what was wrong, but i think that is works now for some reason :s

Answer (score 0):

The new line `\n` is not being interpreted by the `echo` command try adding the `-e` argument to `echo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /testFolder
wget https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/bb2b6b1aefcd70dfd1892149ac3a215f6c636b07/server.jar -O /testFolder/server.jar
echo -e "cd /testFolder\njava -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui" >> /testFolder/startMc.shenter code here
```

Comment: All works great now, not sure why it did'n work before.
It is making new line without `-e` thanks :)